# ORACLE SINGLE GROUP FUNCTION ERROR WITH SUBQUERY

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, count, subquery

I need help

I want execute query like

```
SELECT COUNT(*),
       (SELECT DISTINCT(EMAIL) 
          FROM TABLE2 
         WHERE ID='1') 
  FROM TABLE1 
 WHERE ID='1'
```

Error:

> ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

OK   Lookup Oracle Documentation ...   Copy runtime exception log

Any solution?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: There are at least two interpretations of what you really want (see the answers). Although it is clear why you get the error, it is not at all clear what you expected to get from the query.

Answer (score 3):

I'd avoid subqueries in `SELECT` statement; they rarely do something *good*, might cause bad performance and can - usually - be rewritten as

```
select count(*), t2.email
from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t2.id = t.1.id
group by t2.email
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE1 t1 WHERE t1.ID = x.ID),
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t2.EMAIL) FROM TABLE2 t2 WHERE t2.ID = x.ID)
FROM (SELECT 1 as ID FROM DUAL) x
```